# css icon does not work in my react project

Tags: html, css, reactjs, icons

I found code for a sign in/up with html and css and tried to use it inside my react app but i found that an arrow icon didn't work and dont know why and i feel like the problem inside the css not the html i even asked chatGPT whats the problem with no vain it didnt help

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.checkbox:checked + label,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffeba7;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffeba7;
  background-color: #102770;
  font-family: "unicons";
  content: "\eb4e";
  z-index: 20;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  transform: translateX(44px) rotate(-270deg);
}
```

```
export function Login() {
  return (
    <body>
      <div className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row full-height justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-12 text-center align-self-center py-5">
              <div className="section pb-5 pt-5 pt-sm-2 text-center">
                <h6 className="mb-0 pb-3">
                  <span>Log In </span>
                  <span>Sign Up</span>
                </h6>
                <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log" />
                <label htmlFor="reg-log"></label>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    export function Login() {
  return (
    <body>
      <div className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row full-height justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-12 text-center align-self-center py-5">
              <div className="section pb-5 pt-5 pt-sm-2 text-center">
                <h6 className="mb-0 pb-3">
                  <span>Log In </span>
                  <span>Sign Up</span>
                </h6>
                <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log" />
                <label htmlFor="reg-log"></label>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}

css code 
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.checkbox:checked + label,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffeba7;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before,
.checkbox:not(:checked) + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffeba7;
  background-color: #102770;
  font-family: "unicons"; /* Check if font is loaded correctly */
  content: "\ueb4e"; /* Check if content value is correct */
  z-index: 20;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
  transform: translateX(44px) rotate(-270deg);
}
```

Try This one

Comment: it display like square and yea the font is working fine